# Why does SQL integrated security work from command line but not when invoked from a different process?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, installshield

I have an InstallShield project that invokes an EXE written in C#, passing it some parameters, like so:

```
MyProcess.exe [serverName] [dbName]
```

Internally, this process opens a SQL connection, using the following connection string:

```
Data Source=[serverName];Initial Catalog=[dbName];Integrated Security=True
```

where `[serverName]` and `[dbName]` are the values passed in from the command line.

When I run `MyProcess.exe` directly from my own command line, passing `serverName=localhost` and `dbName=myDB`, it works perfectly.  But when I invoke this exe from my InstallShield script with the same parameters, I get an error:

> Cannot open database "myDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\myusername'.

But `MYDOMAIN\myusername` is a freakin' *admin* on the local database!  I've even put a log line in MyProcess.exe to verify that the connection string is, in fact:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True
```

So the big mystery is: why does it work when I run the command line directly, but not when the *same* command line is run from InstallShield (run by the same Windows user)?  And how to fix this?

Comment: Is MyProcess running with elevated access? Is the command line process?

Comment: @MarcGravell - No, no elevated permissions on either process.

Comment: Specifically what version of InstallShield and project type are you using?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - InstallShield 2009.  Not sure what you mean by project type?  C# executable?

Comment: Start SQL Profiler, open new trace. Try connect from inside InstallShield. In trace gird look for EventClass "Audit Login". WHAT IS in columns "NTUserName"/"LoginName" for this event?

Comment: InstallScript, InstallScript MSI, Basic MSI...

Comment: Courtesy ping to @ChristopherPainter: problem solved see my answer below.

Comment: Courtesy ping to @MarcGravell: problem solved see my answer below.

Comment: Courtesy ping to @Smarty: problem solved see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've worked it out.

The previous step in the installation was to do a restart of the SQL Server service.  We never noticed a problem before, because the databases we were working on before were relatively small - but now the database I'm upgrading using this InstallShield script is a Big Mama of around 20GB.

So - it seems that when restarting a SQL Server, **larger databases take a longer time to come back online**.  This also explains why `MyProcess.exe` ran perfectly with the same parameters later - because by then the DB was back online!

Solution: in the try-catch of the connection to the DB, let it try again (up to `n` times) after a `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: You never did mention what InstallShield project type you are using.  FWIW, InstallShield has native capabilities for defining SQL scripts to execute and you generally shouldn't have to go out of process with InstallScript and C# console apps to get the job done.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - InstallScript.  I'm aware of InstallShield's native capabilities, but I'm working with Somebody Else's Code (who clearly didn't)... ;)